# Numbers and Countries

Tags: formation-of-numbers

The relations given below. According to these values, solve the last relationship.

> Germany - Kenya = 7
>
> Mexico - Brazil = 9
>
> Turkey -  Australia = 18
>
> Norway - Ghana = 7
>
> Korea - Japan = 1
>
> Ethiopia - Colombia = 15
>
> Portugal - Uruguay = ?

I have no clue at all. I thought of geographic side but could not find anything to come close to solve this.

Comment: Hey there! If this question is not yours, could you please tell us where you found it? Questions without attribution may end up being deleted.

Comment: A friend of mine sent it to me.

Comment: could be each letter has a numeric value, but with 6 knowns and about 20 unknowns there may be several solutions, so possibly not.  maybe only some letters have value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **Portugal - Uruguay = 11**

This seems to be related to:

> The distance between the biggest cities of the countries involved. Or, more specifically, the aforementioned distance in miles, divided by 500 and rounded down to the next integer.

Examples:

> Germany - Kenya = 7: distance Berlin-Nairobi is about 3950 miles. 3950/500 = **7**(.9...)
>  Mexico - Brazil = 9: distance Mexico City-São Paulo is about 4600 miles. 4600/500 = **9**(.2...)
>  Turkey - Australia = 18: distance Istanbul-Sydney is about 9300 miles. 9300/500 = **18**(.6...)
>  Norway - Ghana = 7: distance Oslo-Accra is about 3800 miles. 3800/500 = **7**(.6...)
>  (South) Korea - Japan = 1: distance Seoul-Tokyo is about 700 miles. 700/500 = **1**(.4...)
>  Ethiopia - Colombia = 15: distance Addis Ababa-Bogota is about 7700 miles. 7700/500 = **15**(.4...)

As for the final one:

> Portugal - Uruguay = 11: distance Lisbon-Montevideo is about 5900 miles. 5900/500 = **11**(.8...)

Comment: This community hosts some geniuses! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, here I gave may be some kind of stupid answer... in the way of lateral-thinking I assume.

Since OP didn't mentioned whether this is a mathematical puzzle or not.

The answer is...

> Portugal - Uruguay = 22

in 1st and 4th equation, I found that...

> [European country] = [African country] + 7

as for 6th equation...

> [African country] = [South American country] + 15

from those clues above...

> [European country] 
>  
>  = ([South American country] + 15) + 7
>  
>  = [South American country] + 22
>  
>  Finally, we prove that "Portugal - Uruguay = 22".

Comment: Answer is 11 but do not know how.